# Cycle through fields on a continuous subreport

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a report im generating and need to put together a string with some of the numbers in one of the subreports.  I tried to get the recordset with DAO.recordset but i get an error saying that recordset cant use DAO.  This is a database with an linked database.  Is there another way to get the recordset or just cycle through the records and pull the info from fields in a subreport.

Comment: How did you try get the recordset? form's `RecordsetClone` property should return a copy of recordset, which can be used for your purposes.

Comment: its a report so I used both; a reference to the record Recordset to set a variable as well as record RecordsetClone.  Both came up with the same error

Comment: Table(s) in the recordsource are MS Access tables or SQL linked? If SQL in some cases you need to use ADO instead of DAO.

Comment: Ok I will try ADO tonight when i work on it and let you know if that helps

Comment: so ADO didnt work, however I ended up recreating the sql statement from the record data to filter the way i needed and just created a new query and cycled through that recordset with DAO and it worked